# Django: trans and blocktrans not escaping modulo (%)

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm trying to makemessages on a template that has a translation which contains a modulo, like this;

```
{% trans "100% escaping problems sucks" %}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: errors happened while running xgettext on site.html
./templates/site.html.py:34: warning: 'msgid' format string with unnamed 
arguments cannot be properly localized:

The translator cannot reorder the arguments.
Please consider using a format string with named arguments,
and a mapping instead of a tuple for the arguments.
```

And if I try to escape it like this;

```
{% trans "100%% escaping problems sucks" %}
```

I get this error;

```
Error: errors happened while running xgettext on site.html.py
xgettext: error while opening "./templates/site.html.py" for 
reading: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea why it is looking for ./templates/site.html.py .. it should be ./templates/site.html

Any idea ?

Edit: I forgot the Django version, it's 1.2.0 beta1

Answer (score 0):

As per [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4982) you might try upgrading to at least 1.2.1...